# The measure of a Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

So I am trying to argue that the set of points in $[0,1]$ which will not have $4$ in their decimal expansion has measure $0$. So I am thinking to construct a step function such that this set is a null set hence it will have measure $0$. But I am kind stuck in constructing such step functions, any hints?

Comment: Approximate the set from above and use continuity of measure.  If you've considered the "middle-third" Cantor set in the past, this is no different.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\begin{align*}
\frac1{10}+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac9{10}+\frac1{10}\left(\frac9{10}\right)^2+\ldots&=\frac1{10}\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac9{10}\right)^n\\
&=\frac1{10}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac9{10}}\\
&=1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @worthytom1025: No, I’m suggesting that you look at the measure of the complementary subset of $[0,1]$ instead.